# Consolidate JUnits on to a single portal

Tags: junit, automated-tests, fitnesse

I would like to consolidate all my jUnits onto a single web portal (like fitnesse) and build them every night for a consolidated report. Are there any opensource tools available for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need continuous integration system, such as [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). You could write Ant script to compile and run your test cases periodically.